# How to track entity in OData?

Tags: php, odata

I am using the PHP OData sdk (odata.org) and am trying to add a link between a new object and two existing objects:

```
//Add a new object to the database. Pass in objects $v and $o.
public function addB($v,$o) {

    //Create a new object
    $b = new B();
    $b->V = $v;
    $b->O = $o;

    //Add a link between my objects
    $proxy->AddLink($b, 'V', $v);
    $proxy->AddLink($b, 'O', $o);

    $proxy->SaveChanges();
}
```

Using the generation instructions on the odata.org website to generate the proxy class and such.

I am getting the following exception message:

```
The context is not currently tracking the entity.
```

which translates as the proxy class has not got a reference to the objects `$v` or `$o` stored anywhere. One way to add an object to the proxy class's references is:

```
$proxy->AddToVCollection($v);
```

except when I do that and try to save I get primary key conflicts, because it is then trying to save the `$v` object as a new entry.

So, how do I get my proxy class to track my objects `$v` and `$o` so when I do `$proxy->AddLink($b, 'V', $v);` I don't get the above exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know why the objects `$v` and `$o` out of the parameters are not being tracked, but I have had to re-call them from the proxy before I can add them to the object `$b`:

```
//Add a new object to the database. Pass in objects $v and $o.
public function addB($v,$o) {

    //Recreate my existing objects from Service
    $o = $proxy->OCollection()->Filter("id eq '".$o->getId()."'")->Execute()->Result[0];
    $v = $proxy->VCollection()->Filter("id eq '".$v->getId()."'")->Execute()->Result[0];

    //Create a new object
    $b = new B();
    $b->V = $v;
    $b->O = $o;

    //Add a link between my objects
    $proxy->AddLink($b, 'V', $v);
    $proxy->AddLink($b, 'O', $o);

    $proxy->SaveChanges();
}
```

The proxy will begin tracking an object when you call Execute. In this scenario I only need to link the objects `$v` and `$o`, but they have links themselves which I `Expand()` in the original request before sending those in as parameters to the `addB()` function. Could it be that `Expand()` is somehow stopping the proxy from tracking the objects?